# I can't install ffmpeg

Tags: apt, package-management, ffmpeg, dependencies

When installing ffmpeg with `sudo apt install ffmpeg` I get this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ffmpeg : Depends: libavcodec59 (= 7:5.1.2-0ubuntu1~22.04.sav2)
          Depends: libavfilter8 (= 7:5.1.2-0ubuntu1~22.04.sav2)
          Depends: libavformat59 (= 7:5.1.2-0ubuntu1~22.04.sav2)
 libavdevice59 : Depends: libavcodec59 (= 7:5.1.2-0ubuntu1~22.04.sav2)
                 Depends: libavfilter8 (= 7:5.1.2-0ubuntu1~22.04.sav2)
                 Depends: libavformat59 (= 7:5.1.2-0ubuntu1~22.04.sav2)
                 Depends: libsndio7 (>= 1.8.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

I don't know much about linux, so I am not very knowledgeable about how to solve the problem, here is my system [info](https://pastebin.com/YEVE1TLD). Here is my listed packages `sudo apt list`, [mediafire because the logs are huge](https://www.mediafire.com/file/ke298wewy2tcwv4/logs.txt/file).

Comment: What is your Linux distro? Your *info* link seems to be a private or broken.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you added a non-standard repository to your system. The suffix "sav2" lets me assume it is [https://launchpad.net/~savoury1/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg4](https://launchpad.net/%7Esavoury1/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg4). While there is nothing inherently wrong with using third party repositories, the implications can be quite tricky to understand. Hence I do not recommend it to beginners.

You can try installing `ppa-purge`. Then run

```
sudo ppa-purge -o savoury1
```

to remove the offending repository from your system (and all the packages it offers). Then `sudo apt install ffmpeg` has a chance to succeed.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Hermann's answer, that you possibly use `ppa:savoury1/ffmpeg4` as repository for fresh `ffmpeg` packages.

The problem with it, that this PPA doesn't work anymore and is broken. Rob Savoury, its owner, offers now its service only to donaters. He started with ffmpeg, and, possibly will break also another his public PPAs.

Citate from his profile:

> UPDATE (24 Mar 2023): The PPAs at this Launchpad site are now moving
> to a subscriber only (those who have donated) system.

[https://launchpad.net/~savoury1](https://launchpad.net/%7Esavoury1)

If you want to use his packages futher, you can follow updates on his [Patreon](https://www.patreon.com/savoury1)

And now your best solution would be just to purge all his public PPAs from your system, as it stated in @Hermann's answer.

> `sudo ppa-purge -o savoury1`

Comment: @Peregrino69, thanks.

Comment: @Peregrino69 to be fair, Alex's answer actually "answered" the question I had when I landed here from Google. I, like the OP, use savoury1 PPA. Due to launchpad's formatting, It's not easy to notice what's wrong with this PPA, and Alex provided exactly the answer I needed, which is "look for alternatives"

Comment: @Peregrino69, thanks for clarifying. I've updated the answer. Does it now meet requirements?

Comment: @AlexAnder Peregrino isn't the Be All and End All of deciding whether or not answers are good and acceptable.  Revision 2 of your answer was perfectly fine.

Comment: @Peregrino69 *you* don't have enough reputation to be an Answer Nazi.  If you don't think an answer is adequate, then **vote. it. down.**  The rest of us will up-vote it if we think it's good.

Comment: @Peregrino69 even worse is when you hijack other people's edits for your own benefit.

Comment: @Felix-Borzik, thanks! I actually broke my system, upgrading with "apt full-upgrade" with sleepy head and without paying much attention on what will be done. And it took some time to find the source of problem the next day. 
This was main reason to write this answer here, so others could also know, what's going on. 
I don't mind, if the Rob goes to donates, he did a huge work after all. But happening it so unexpected had frustrated me. And it can frustrate many people too.

Comment: Yap, the first revision already clarified what's broken :-) @RonJon, I have absolutely no clue what you mean by me "hijacking other people's edits" or what "benefit" could I ever gain from it. Alex's answer came up in [review](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/reviews-intro). I have a bad habit of leaving personal advice reviewing new members' postings and if my meaning isn't clear I take the trouble of explaining. If my comments become redundant, I tend to remove them. Just like I did here. If you have a problem with my comments, please do feel free to flag them.